# Convert type [key: string]: number to this type Array< [string, number]>

Tags: angular, typescript

I Get a `Map<String,Long>` as  `[key: string]: number` from the backend. I want to convert this map to the this type like: `Array< [string, number]>`.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which does exactly that.

```
const map: { [key: string]: number } = {
  thing1: 1,
  thing2: 2,
  thing3: 3,
};

const arrayified = Object.entries(map);
// const arrayified: [string, number][]
```

`arrayified` will now be an array of `[string, number]` tuples :)